# create tabs inside nody body

Tags: routes, blocks

I want to create tabs inside the node body and so I found the [yui_tabview module](http://drupal.org/project/yui_tabview) but it only works in Drupal 6. Anyone know a module that works for Druapl 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal has [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) built right in so you'd be better off leveraging that if possible. This is a standard theme function I chuck into most projects to help with this sort of thing:

```
function theme_tabs($vars) {
  if (empty($vars['items'])) {
    return '';
  }

  $js_added = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, FALSE);
  static $delta = 0;

  if (!$js_added) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.tabs');
    drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('.tabs-container').tabs(); });", 'inline');
    $js_added = TRUE;
  }

  $tabs = $content = '';
  foreach ($vars['items'] as $key => $item) {
    if (isset($item['#access']) && !$item['#access']) {
      continue;
    }

    $tabs .= '<li><a href="#' . $key . '-tab-' . $delta . '">' . $item['title'] . '</a></li>';
    $content .= '<div id="' . $key . '-tab-' . $delta . '">' . render($item['content']) . '</div>';
  }

  $delta++;

  return '<div class="tabs-container">' ."<ul>$tabs</ul>$content</div>";
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
$tabs = array(
  'tab1' => array(
    'title' => 'Title for tab 1',
    'content' => 'Content for tab 1' // Note this can be a string or standard Drupal render array
  ),
  'tab2' => array(
    'title' => 'Title for tab 2',
    'content' => 'Content for tab 2' 
  ),
  // etc.
);

$args = array('items' => $tabs);
print theme_tabs($args);
```

Of course if you're doing this 'properly' you would register the theme function in a module like so:

```
function MYMODULE_theme() {
  return array(
    'tabs' => array(
      'variables' => array('items' => array())
    )
  );
}
```

and call it like this instead:

```
print theme('tabs', array('items' => $tabs));
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: @downvoter I can't imagine what you've found objectionable about this, care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [Quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module

Are you aware of [drupalmodules.com](http://drupalmodules.com/)?

Comment: Quick tabs will not allow tabs inside a node body, i believe